# Passing id to jquery function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a button and a hidden div.

Button:

```
<input 
type="button" 
id="myButton" 
name="answer" 
value="OPTIONS" 
style=" margin-top: -30px; margin-bottom: 10px;float: right;background-color: #C80918;border: none;color: #ffffff" 
onclick="showDiv()" />
```

Hidden div:

```
<div id="customDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > WELCOME</div>
```

I have included a function to hide/show the div:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
  $('#customDiv').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

The button and the div are included inside a PHP loop. There is an identifier for every loop, it is `$row['id']`.

Now, when the button is clicked, only the first item from the loop is showing its div, I would need to pass the id to the jquery function to identify which button/item is clicked.

How could I change my code to pass the id of every loop item to the jquery function?

EDIT

```
<?php

//output customizable

$customizable = $row["customizable"];


if ($customizable == 1){

  $output .= '
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="margin-top:12px;">  

    <div class="item-content" >

    <button type="button" style="float: right;background-color: Transparent;border: none;"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPort"
    data-id="'.$row["id"].'" ><img src="info.png" width=30 

    ></button>


    <div class="img-container">
    
    <img src="../administrar/application/admin/productos/'.$row["image"].'" class="img-responsive" /><br />

    <h4 class="text-info" style= "color:#666">'.$row["nombre"].'</h4>
    
    <h4 class="text-info" style= "color:#000"><strong>'.$row["name"].'<strong></h4>
    <h5 class="text-info" style= "color:#000">'.$row['descripcion'].'</h5>
    <h4 class="text-danger" style= "color:#000">$ '.$row["price"] .'</h4>

     
<input 
type="button" 
id="myButton" 
name="answer" 
value="OPTIONS" 
style=" margin-top: -30px; margin-bottom: 10px;float: right;background-color: #C80918;border: none;color: #ffffff" 
onclick="showDiv()" />

    <input style= " color:#000" type="text" name="comentarios" id="comentarios' . $row["id"] .'"  placeholder="Special Instructions" class="form-control" value="" />
    <br>
    ';

    if($statement_opc->execute())
    {
      $numero_opciones = 0;
      $result_opc = $statement_opc->fetchAll();
      foreach($result_opc as $row_opc)
      {



        if ($row_opc['producto'] == $row['id']) {
          
          $numero_opciones = $numero_opciones + 1;
          $output .= '
          <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" data-nombre="'. $row_opc["nombre"] .'" 
    data-precio="'. $row_opc["precio"] .'"  id="opcion'.$row["id"].'"   class="opcion_cbox" 
    data-rowid="'. $row["id"] .'"  value="">'.$row_opc['nombre'].' (+ $'.$row_opc['precio'].')</label>
          </div>


        
          ';

        }
      }
    }
?>
//zona custom


  <?php
   $output .= '

   <div id="customDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > WELCOME</div>





   ';
  ?>


  
    //fin zona custom
```

Comment: Do all of the divs have the same id? cause that violates some html principles.

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is a class instead of an id? That way you can get an array of all divs with the same class in Jquery?

Comment: @nickzoum, yes at the moment. This is part of my question, every loop has a different $row['id'] value. I would need to add this value to the id value of the button?

Comment: You should paste more code to see what you are doing in loop. According to me you should give unique id to both button and customDiv.

And also you should bind function with this keyword to know which element is clicked

Because of same id, it picks the first element from the loop and toggle it accordingly.

Comment: Are the buttons and divs generated programmatically or do they already exist in the html?

Comment: @MandeepSingh, yes, that's my question, how can I add the needed $row['id'] variable to identify the button and the div that should be detected to launch the jquery function.

Comment: @nickzoum, they are included as part of the loop

Comment: HI, where are you showing that `$row['id']` ?

Comment: maybe you can use index of the loop to add it in id of both button and div, something like customDiv1, myButton1, customDiv2, myButton2.....so on

Comment: @Swati, it is not shown in my question. In the code I can get it wherever I need inside the loop.

Comment: show your code with loops then .

Comment: @Swati, done, I have included the code for the loop.

Comment: this `<div id="customDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >..` is different for every row ? also its not under for loop ?

Comment: @Swati, yes it is under the row. That is my issue, how should I identify its id and pass it to the jquery function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could connect each button to the respective div using their individual index (so the first button will toggle the first div, the second will toggle the second...)

```js
var buttons = $("input[type='button']");
var answers = $(".answer-list");

buttons.each(function(index, dom) {
  $(dom).on("click", function(e) {
    $(answers[index]).toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: block;
  height: 120px;
}

input[type="button"] {
  background-color: #C80918;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /*margin-top: -30px;*/
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  border: none;
}

.answer-list {
  display: none;
}

.answer-list.slow {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="OPTIONS 1" />
<input type="button" value="OPTIONS 2" />
<input type="button" value="OPTIONS 3" />

<div class="answer-list">WELCOME 1</div>
<div class="answer-list">WELCOME 2</div>
<div class="answer-list">WELCOME 3</div>
```

Or you could have unique ids for each div and just somehow store that id in a data attribute in the respective button.

```js
$("input[type='button']").on("click", function(e) {
  $($(e.target).data("target")).toggle("show");
});
```

```css
body {
  display: block;
  height: 120px;
}

input[type="button"] {
  background-color: #C80918;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /*margin-top: -30px;*/
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  border: none;
}

.answer-list {
  display: none;
}

.answer-list.slow {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" data-target="#answer-list-1" value="OPTIONS 1" />
<input type="button" data-target="#answer-list-2" value="OPTIONS 2" />
<input type="button" data-target="#answer-list-3" value="OPTIONS 3" />

<div class="answer-list" id="answer-list-1">WELCOME 1</div>
<div class="answer-list" id="answer-list-2">WELCOME 2</div>
<div class="answer-list" id="answer-list-3">WELCOME 3</div>
```

But you should never use duplicate ids on the same page or duplicate names on the same form.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do this :

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
  $('#customDiv').each( function() {
    $( this ).toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
  });
});
```

But you may think to change id#customDiv to a class.customDiv.
It's not good let two or more elements with the same id.

EDIT
On button click :

```
var ids = [];
$( 'div.checkbox' ).find( 'input' ).each( function() {
    var currentID = $( this ).data( 'rowid' );
    // Some code, id verification or others 
    ids.push( currentID );
});
```

Now ids contains id of all checkbox.

---

Documentation : 
https://api.jquery.com/find/ 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp 
https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thank you. I have included the code for the loop to make it easier to you to understand what I need

Comment: You already pass ids in loop. You can access these data by using find() of jQuery to reach the input type="checkbox" and then access data with .data() of jQuery.

Comment: You should never have multiple elements with the same id, and you should never use a solution that works around that problem